# How to trap an error with authentication?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

How do I trap an error with authentication? I get a nasty error in the console when I want a graceful fail for bad authentication. My alert for the error will not show:

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire){

  this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            console.log('---->', user)
            if (user) {
              this.user = user.auth.providerData[0];
              if (user.auth.emailVerified==false){
                user.auth.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
                    alert('Email Verification Sent!');
                });
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
              }
    },error => { alert('dude whats up with this?')

  }); 

}



onSubmit(){

      console.log(this.email,this.password)
      this.af.auth.login({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        },
        {
          provider: AuthProviders.Password,
          method: AuthMethods.Password,
        })
    }



XCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The email address is badly formatted.ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:45next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
error_handler.js:50 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
error_handler.js:51 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The email address is badly formatted.
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:429)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:414)
    at zone.js:462
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:34)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:136)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:368)
    at HTMLFormElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:308)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:51next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: The email address is badly formatted. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: R {code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly formatted."} undefinedconsoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The email address is badly formatted.(…)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`login` method](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.5/src/auth/auth.ts#L58) returns a promise, so:

```
this.af.auth.login({
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password,
}, {
  provider: AuthProviders.Password,
  method: AuthMethods.Password,
})
.catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

The `auth` observable is used to emit changes in authentication state - not errors that occur when logging in, etc.